# How to solve a linear program with OR constraints

Tags: linear-programming, operations-research

I have $n$ people. I want assign them to $c$ jobs. A job may be not assigned at all or there must be a minimum and maximum number of people assigned to it. $n$ is about 4000 and $c$ is about 1000.

The linear programming mode is as follows. There is an $OR$ condition in constraints. I have seen some [methods (pp. 78)](http://www.aimms.com/aimms/download/manuals/aimms_modeling.pdf) to add an extra boolean variable $y\in\{0,1\}$ and a large constant $M$.

Is there any simpler model I can use for the problem. Is there any polynomial solution for the problem?

$\min \sum_{i,j} c_{i,j} x_{i,j}$

$s.t.$

$(1)$ $\sum_j x_{i,j}=0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall i=\{1,2,\ldots c\}$

OR

$(2)$  $ 2\leq \sum_j x_{i,j} < 4 \ \ \ \ \forall i=\{1,2,\ldots c\}$

AND

$(3)$ $\sum_i x_{i,j}=1 \ \ \ \ \ \forall j=\{1,2,\ldots n\}$

I mean that $(3)$ is mandatory and at least ($(1)$ or $(2)$) must be true for all $i$ (Any $i$ is considered separetely). $c_{i,j}$ is known.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to add minimum constraints?"

Comment: we can decompose $(2)$ to two separate constraint sets, one for $2\leq$ and another one for $<4$. But this means an extra number of constraints. I with to handle them in a single constraint form. In fact my solver accepts all constraints in the form of $\alpha\leq AX \leq \beta$ and I want to provide a more simpler form for it, if possible.

Comment: Sorry for bad formatting. I am not a mathematician.

Comment: I think it can be converted to a MIP and be solved there. Correct?

Comment: $c$ is about 1000 and $n$ is about 4000. In fact, my problem is about how to decompose the second condition (after introducing an extra boolean variable $y$ and large constant $M$) to a well formed condition $\alpha\leq AX \leq \beta$. I'm not sure if the first equality $=0$ may makes the problem simpler?

Comment: I have added the original problem before modeling to the post

Comment: You can use the equality constraints to get rid of a variable in each of the resulting linear programs. I don't imagine this will save you much work, computationally.

Comment: Would you please see the original problem. If there is any similar problem in the literature you know. (Its similar to assignment or minimum cost network problems, but the first condition is not a constraint in them). I mean there may be a better formulation for my problem.

Comment: Do you mean that (constraint 1 is true for all $i$) or (constraint 2 is true for all $i$)? Or do you mean that (constraint 1 is true or constraint 2 is true) for all $i$? I think you mean the latter, but it would be good to edit the question to make it perfectly clear.

Comment: Yes, The later one is true. Any $i$ is considered separately.

Answer (score 1):

A linear program must be posed such that the feasible set is a convex polytope. In your case, it is easy to simply solve two separate linear programs and combine the result, however. One program satisfies (1) and (3), while one satisfies (2) and (3). Solve these programs separately, and pick whichever has lower optimal objective value.

Comment: In my problem $i$ is about 4000 and this means an extra number of tries! not possible for me. If I can formulate it in a single problem, I can use benefits of advanced methods such as branch and bound (for integer program)

Comment: $i$ is a dummy variable, do you mean $c$? what about $n$? how big is $n$?

Comment: I have $n$ people. I want to assign them to $c$ jobs. A job may be not assigned at all or there must be a minimum number of people assigned to it. $n$ is about 4000 and $c$ is about 1000.
$i$ is used as the index of jobs and $j$ as the index of people.